# Cropping by 1px while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: c, image, interpolation, gstreamer, video-processing

I am using gstreamer to simulate camera movement in a video stream. I have a 4K video and I want to extract a 1080p image that can be both cropped and scaled from the original.
The process needs to be really smooth.

I am currently using the gstreamer videocrop and videoscale elements and I update the element properties to set the coordinates of the image I want to extract.
The process I tried is the following:

- I specify the coordinates of a region of interest of any size.
- I set this ROI as a target
- A function is called and crops 1px of the image along the coordinate that is the furthest from its destination while trying to maintain the aspect ratio.
- I sleep a few ms
- I repeat the function until the destination is reached or I have a new one

The issue I have right now is that when I crop only 1px in some axis I can't get a perfect aspect ratio anymore.

I could remove 16px and 9px each time to stay in 16:9 but it would appear odd right ?

I am wondering if there is some sort of interpolation algorithm that handles this problem. I did not find anything relevant though.
Any idea or comments ?

Comment: If you want to remove 1 pixel at a time I suggest you can either remove it horizontally or vertically. If the crop ratio is ≥ 16:9 remove the strip from the nearer of the left or right edge. Otherwise remove the strip from the nearer of the top or bottom edge.

Comment: Thanks, so if I want a perfect aspect ratio I iterate cropping pixels in both dimensions until I have it ? I am concerned about the smoothness of the transition if so. It may not be so awful on large pictures (I have been testing in 640x480 until now)

Comment: Perhaps a better transition is to always crop left or right, and also crop the top/bottom if it goes under 16:9. Then the major dimension is changing smoothly.

Comment: I will try it out I let you know when I have results.